# Installing windows service gives me an error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have created windows service using C#.net(VS-2010). When its installing into my local machine using visual studio command prompt throw me an error.

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

I have tried to solve by past questions, but it didn't help me.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //Get data from UAL database            
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Server=192.168.2.7;Port=3306;Database=ual;Uid=ualusr;Pwd=ualtest;";
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Department", conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    MySqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (Reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (!Reader.IsDBNull(0))
                        {
                            string Id = Reader.GetString(0);
                            MessageBox.Show("Id = " + Id);
                        }
                    }
                    Reader.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Show us code, stack traces... useful information.

Comment: I have mentioned it above..

Comment: You're showing us code that runs when the service starts - but you've not even got as far as having the service installed, so all of that code never runs. And you've not shown us the code for the installer components.

Comment: I have only changed ProjectInstaller Property as "StartType = Automatic".

Comment: Its asking user name and password for install the service? If in case asking means that given user need to have execute permission for that machine.

Comment: @Sambath: Yeah its came login screen till i'm not use of following code,

this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

Comment: Check your Administrator for given user account has extensive privileges on the local computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install a service you need to have administrative rights. You will have to run the command prompt as an administrator: right-click on the command prompt shortcut and select **Run as administrator**. (This assumes that your user account is member of the Administrators group and that you are using User Account Control.)

Comment: I have tried it Martin. Its gives me this error,

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and secur
ity IDs was done

Comment: @Kanishka: That is a different problem and probably has to do with the user account you want to use for the service being invalid. However, you have not provided any information in your question about how you install the service.

Comment: I tried to install in my local machine (Windows 8 64bit).

Comment: In my case the login was in a wrong format "domain\username" did the trick